# What is meant by these criteria for a stabilized approach?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, approach

Based on regulation, there are several criteria for when an approach is stabilized. I want to ask:

1. > Only small changes in heading/pitch.

   How small?
2. > The aircraft is in correct landing configuration.

   What are those configurations?
3. > The aircraft speed is not more than Vref+20 or less Vref.

   Is this IAS or CAS or TAS?

Comment: As far as I know, stabilized approach criteria are defined by the airline, not in any regulation.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! For questions about regulations, please always tell us which country or regulator you're asking about. Regulations can be very different in different places. And when you quote a source, it's always good to tell us what that source is, and link to it if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Although I can’t find regulations regarding stabilized approaches in the FAR/AIM, the unofficial but generally accepted definition of a stabilized approach would be

1. “Only small changes in heading/pitch.
   How small?”
   *Small changes in heading and pitch would mean changes only necessary to maintain a ground track on the lateral guidance and a consistent airspeed on the glideslope. These are to compensate for drift due to things such as wind.*
2. “The aircraft is in correct landing configuration.
   What are those configurations?“
   *Configuration is entirely dependent on the aircraft and situation.
   Typically it would include things like:

   Autopilot correctly set or off;

   Boost pump on;

   Carb heat to hot;

   Gas on the fullest tank, both, or on;

   Landing gear down and locked with indicator lights lit;

   Cowl flaps closed;

   Flaps at the correct setting;

   Mixture set at best power for density altitude;

   Prop speed set at fastest setting;

   Landing, position, and anti-collision lights (if not in clouds or fog) on;

   All auxiliary and/or unnecessary equipment off;

   Sterile cockpit;

   Seats and seatback set and locked in the upright position;

   Seatbelts and shoulder harnesses on and latched;

   Throttle/power set at a consistent setting to provide a descent rate on the glideslope;

   Landing checklists complete.*
3. “The aircraft speed is not more than Vref+20 or less Vref.
   Is this IAS or CAS or TAS?“
   *Vref is usually in IAS. Especially since the occasion in which you are using it would be below 3000 feet AGL, and less than 200 knots.*

Comment: thank you so much for the help! btw for the heading/pitch changes, is there any exact number? ex 3 or 5 degree

Comment: Constant rate (vertical speed) descents and constant speed (airspeed) descents are very similar to straight & level, unaccelerated flight. A 1-3° adjustment/compensation is normal. A 3-5° adjustment/compensation is extreme, but not uncommon. Per my instructor, over 5° would be unstabilized. Over 10° would be a deviation from lateral or vertical guidance; lack of directional control; leveling off for a MDA, circling approach or missed approach; or, an actual missed approach or go-around. The rate and frequency at which you make these changes is also a factor. Your instructor may see different.

Comment: thank you so much!!!